# How to display stub component when component is not found in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to catch situation, when component is not found, ie:

```js
{
   template: '<some-unknown-component></some-unknown-component>'
}
```

At that moment, Vue warns us with `unknown custom element: <some-unknown-component>...`

I would like to step in when `some-unknown-component` is not found and then use another component instead, like `stub-component`:

```js
{
   name: 'stub-component',
   props: ['componentName'],
   template: '<p>component ${componentName} does not exists, click here to create...</p>'
}
```

UPDATE: I am looking for solution without changing the template itself, so no `v-if` and `component` added.

Comment: I'm trying to think of an answer unless someone beats me to it. I'm not aware of a straightforward way. However, I have a question. In what scenario would you ever have a custom element tag that doesn't exist, which can't be fixed in your code?

Comment: I have my own ide, where i would like to write my code and create components later. Also, I would like to customize way how the components are searched and loaded (some kind of webpack alternative)

Answer (score 1):

Vue exposes a global error and warning handler. I managed to get a working solution by using the global warnHandler. I don't know if it is exactly what you are looking for, but it may be a good starting point. See the working snippet (I think it is quite self explanatory).

```js
Vue.config.warnHandler = function (err, vm, info)  {
  if (err.includes("Unknown custom element:")) {
    let componentName = err.match(/<.*>/g)[0].slice(1, -1)
    
    vm.$options.components[componentName] = Vue.component('stub-component', {
       props: ['componentName'],
       template: `<p>component "${componentName}" does not exists, click here to create...</p>`,
    });
    
    vm.$forceUpdate()
  } else {
    console.warn(err)
  }
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <unknown-component></unknown-component>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. It seems working pretty well and is easy to add/remove.

Answer (score 0):

Vue stores the details of all the registered components in the `$options.component` property of the Vue instance.

So, you can check for the component availability using `this.$options.component` and if the component is present then load the component otherwise load the other component.

In the below example, suppose you have two different components and you want to load them on the availability, then you can create a computed property on the basis of it, load the component as needed.

```js
var CustomComponent = Vue.extend({ template: '<h2>A custom Component</h2>' });

var AnotherComponent = Vue.extend({ template: '<h2>Custom component does not exist.</h2>' });

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    CustomComponent,
    AnotherComponent
  },
  computed: {
    componentAvailable () {
      return this.$options.components.CustomComponent
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-if="componentAvailable">
    <custom-component />
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <another-component />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the problem is different. I do not want to do any wrapping in `v-if` etc. I would like just use custom-component in template and then "somehow" find correct component or pass stub component.